# how to Integrate my custom php application into joomla?

Tags: php, codeigniter, joomla

Maybe there is some links or tutorials for that but found nothing for this, 
my problem is that I have a joomla 3 application and some components installed on it like seo and shopping cart,

and i have another php application (it uses codeigniter php framework), now i want to some integration between this two,

for example: i have some users , some user groups and some access levels in joomla3 installation, now i want all joomla users can login to my custom application with their joomla username/password, or better if a user logins to joomla (frontend or backend) he/she be able to use my application without need to login again,

or , i be able to check user's joomla ACLs and user groups within my custom application.

one way my be connect to joomla DB and read data, there are 2 problems also, joomla encrypt passwords so i need do the same (how) , and it will be perfect if there is some API or classes for using them in my custom application.

and other way (that i think i can use) to create some components for joomla and create my own apis in it and include/use them in my application (but how?)

any one can please help me to solve this? i am very little experience with creating joomla component.

Comment: WOW, It has a very simple solution, many thanks to http://perfexionit.com, here is 2 article about integrate joomla+codeigniter : http://perfexionit.com/codeigniter-joomla-integration-part-1/    and  http://perfexionit.com/codeigniter-joomla-integration-part-2/

Comment: You should answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple run any php code like a joomla component.

All you need is create a folder with the prefix `com_` (*com_mycode*) and inside create a php file  with the same name without the prefix (*mycode.php*)

- components

  - com_mycode

    - mycode.php

It will be your main code, you can organize your app code starting by this file.

To more integration, you must give further information about what you need to do, and we can find the specific joomla object that you can use.

Comment: the most important things for me just now is current joomla user, so i can use it for recording history or serve other data to him, and then access ACL rules defined in joomla, now i want to use my application as some iframes in joomla site (it works well without any additional config) just there is a small problem, http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62638-post-321470.html#pid321470  , i will try to create a joomla component and call/execute my application within its controller and i will try post result, thanks for your guide,

Comment: just i wonder how is it possible to use joomla ACL in my codeigniter application?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating a component is to create a module. What's nice about a module is it can be placed into a position on one page or multiple pages. For example, a custom login module could reside in the header, footer, or sidebar of each page.

First, create a new mod_ directory in /modules, like mod_mylogin.

Then, create a blank index.html file, an XML file named mod_mylogin.xml, and a PHP file named mod_mylogin.php. Additional files, like include files, even directories, can be added, as well.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><body></body></html>
```

mod_mylogin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="3.1" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>mod_mylogin</name>
    <author>Your Name</author>
    <creationDate>September 2023</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>admin@joomla.org</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <description>MY LOGIN</description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_mylogin">mod_mylogin.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field  name="text_1"
                        type="text" 
                        label="Text 1"
                        description="Enter text 1"
                />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

mod_mylogin.php

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// For example, you can use Joomla's JFactory to access info for users already logged in
$user = JFactory::getUser();
// you don't have to define new variables, but this just shows you some of what's available 
$user_id = $user->id;
$user_name = $user->name;

// Your PHP, HTML, etc goes on this page
echo "<h2>Hello ".$user_name."</h2>";
// values defined in the admin area can be retrieved using $params->get()
echo "<p>".$params->get('text_1')."</p>";
?>
```

Then, you have to go through the process of adding the module. Here are the steps:

If you've created the new mod_mylogin directory in /modules, then go to the administrator area and go do Extensions, Manage, Discover. Click on the Discover button, and then you'll see your new module. Check the box next to its name, and click the Install button.

Next, go to Extensions, Modules, click on the green New button, and select your new module from the list.

Once it's added in as a module, you can add it to pages and manage permissions. Go to Extensions, then Modules. Click on your module's name to go to its admin page. Notice the text field added in by the XML file. You can add as many as you want. It's great for creating variables in your PHP that have values defined in that admin area, especially if you have admin users that need to come in and make changes, like new welcome text.